# Display Data From This Custom Media Upload Meta Box?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

This plugin is working without any issue on CMS. Now I need to know how to properly display them in my post.

Custom Media Upload Meta Box Plugin.

```
$meta_box_media_upload = new Meta_Box_Media_Upload();

class Meta_Box_Media_Upload {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'setup_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_box' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    function setup_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'meta_box_id', __( 'Meta Box Media Upload', 'some-meta-box' ), array( $this, 'meta_box_contents' ), 'post', 'side' );
    }

    function meta_box_contents() {

        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-box-media', plugins_url('js/media.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

        wp_nonce_field( 'nonce_action', 'nonce_name' );

        // one or more
        $field_names = array( 'meta-box-media-name' );

        foreach ( $field_names as $name ) {

            $value = $rawvalue = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), $name, true );

            $name = esc_attr( $name );
            $value = esc_attr( $name );

            echo "<input type='hidden' id='$name-value'  class='small-text'       name='meta-box-media[$name]'            value='$value' />";
            echo "<input type='button' id='$name'        class='button meta-box-upload-button'        value='Upload' />";
            echo "<input type='button' id='$name-remove' class='button meta-box-upload-button-remove' value='Remove' />";

            $image = ! $rawvalue ? '' : wp_get_attachment_image( $rawvalue, 'full', false, array('style' => 'max-width:100%;height:auto;') );

            echo "<div class='image-preview'>$image</div>";

            echo '<br />';

        }

    }

    function save_box( $post_id, $post ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce_name'] ) ) //make sure our custom value is being sent
            return;
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce_name'], 'nonce_action' ) ) //verify intent
            return;
        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) //no auto saving
            return;
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) //verify permissions
            return;

        $new_value = array_map( 'intval', $_POST['meta-box-media'] ); //sanitize
        foreach ( $new_value as $k => $v ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $k, $v ); //save
        }

    }

}
```

I have a question with meta key `' ??? '` value. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
    <article class="post">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        // HERE....
        <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ' ??? ', true ); ?>" />

    </article>
```

Comment: Actually I don't understand, what the problem is, are you asking about which key to use or what

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "esc_attr" in case your value contains a quote for exemple

```
<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(...));?>
```